# Settlement: if a company pressures you to quit, is pushback going to harm your career?

Tags: united-kingdom

A company is the UK is pressuring me to quit, probably because in a few months I will have additional legal protections after reaching 2 years of employment.

The accusations are one sided, and some of them are blatantly false, e.g. blaming me for making a comment in a meeting I didn't attend.

If I do nothing, I will probably be out of this job soon.
If I get back to the company with my list of complaints and grievances, I might take one or two managers down with me, or at least damage their reputation, but I will still be out of a job, and seen a "dangerous" from management anyway.

I lose either way. Maybe if I use my "list" I will get a settlement.

The question is: would pushing back to negotiate a settlement damage my career and reputation?

Comment: Mono because your question is so good and important, I **edited it**.  It goes without saying, on these sites, if you don't like someone's helpful-edit™, just simply trivilally click the "undo edit" button.  Good luck!

Comment: Is it possible to rebut the accusations *without* also bringing other complaints and grievances into it? Pushing back but not throwing anyone under the bus in the process. Then you negotiate settlement without burning any bridges.

Comment: The notion that a two-year employee can "take down one or two managers" is delusional, unless blatantly criminal activity was involved (and "blaming somebody for something" is not a criminal offense, even if it ended as a libel action in court...

Comment: Why do you think your "list" would get you a settlement? Does it consist of complaints about illegal or legally questionable things that they could get sued over? Have you tried pointing out the problem with accusations against you? If no, why not? If yes, how did that go? Have you considered or tried finding another job so you no longer have to deal with this problem or this company you clearly seem to not be super happy with?

Comment: I don't think we can really provide a useful answer to this question in its current state, but I do think "How do I deal with my employer making false or one-sided accusations against me" might make for a good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're under the 2 year mark they don't *need* you to quit, they can already get rid of you for anything that isn't an "automatically unfair" reason. So if they want you gone then all they have to do is not be monumentally idiotic in how they handle it, you the contractual notice and it's Bye Felicia!

> The accusations are one sided, and some of them are blatantly false, e.g. blaming me for making a comment in a meeting I didn't attend.

This sucks - but there's probably not much you can really do about it, unless you have hard evidence of something illegal or that would count for the aforementioned automatically unfair dismissal.

> If I do nothing, I will probably be out of this job soon. If I get back to the company with my list of complaints and grievances, I might take one or two managers down with me, or at least damage their reputation, but I will still be out of a job, and seen a "dangerous" from management anyway.

Since they are already treating you this badly why on earth would you want to stay? Applying some sort of scorched earth policy on the way out is, as you fear one way to cause yourself additional harm. Depending on your industry/sector professional reputation *can* matter. Maybe you'll never run into any repercussions, but why take the risk? What is there to be gained? Even if you succeed in "taking one or two managers down" or damaging their reputation it gains you nothing - besides possibly a bit of short-lived schadenfreude.

> I lose either way. Maybe if I use my "list" I will get a settlement.

If they are pushing you to quit (as opposed to simply firing you) then that indicates they would *prefer* you to go quietly/of your own volition. If that's the case then they might be willing to give you something in return - so rather than going in guns blazing and hoping to get something you can approach this as a sales negotiation, if they want you to quit ask them what they are prepared to offer you to do that. It might not be much - maybe just a reduced notice period with full notice period pay that sort of thing. But play it right and you might get *something* tangible without getting burned at all. You don't ask, you don't get and all that.

On last thought on your "list" - if you **do** have anything that would constitute something illegal or automatically unfair as a reason for dismissal then make sure you have it all documented and have a word with an employment solicitor or ACAS as soon as practicable and get your ducks in a row. It doesn't mean you have to act unless you want to - but it does mean if the situation deteriorates sharply you're ready and can respond immediately and avoid getting railroaded.

Answer (score 10):

> would pushing back to negotiate a settlement damage my career and reputation?

That depends on how influential and well connected the people you intend to take down are within your industry.

If they have plenty of good relations with important people at potential places of employment for you, they could attempt to do some harm to your chances of working at those companies.

I would still attempt to settle but not from the perspective of attempting to retaliate or take revenge on these people.  Simply present your side as factually correct as possible without any accusations.  So your example of the comment you allegedly made, rather than accusing them of making "blatantly false" accusations, simply state that you did not attend the specific meeting.  Keep all your grievances focused on facts to reduce any attempts of retaliation on their part.

Comment: While this is every-sentence-priceless material, in a word I urge the OP to pick up the phone to a solicitor.  Even if the solicitor ends up saying "do nothing", OP needs a badass legal rep, at this moment.

Comment: OP - your starting point for the legal route should be Citizens Advice Bureau. They will help you put together what you need, find you legal advice (first hour/session) and advise you your next course of action. All of this is free. The legal help won't be free after that first session, but hopefully you won't need it, and if you do, at least you won't waste their expensive time, as they will be briefed.

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to maximize your settlement then it seems to me that withholding your "list" until you give it to an employment attorney might be the most prudent course of action. Otherwise you're pretty much tipping your hand and giving them time to prepare for fights on those fronts (destroying evidence?).

That said, if you try to retaliate I feel that that could motivate management to spread further (mis)information about you which might hurt you down the line. Like maybe some of your current coworkers will move onto other jobs. What if you, later on down the line, try to apply for those same jobs? Stuff like this can follow you for the rest of your career.

Answer (score 4):

the answer is extremely simple,

1. You need an employment solicitor at this time - literally today.
2. *Of course, obviously*, your solicitor will use the information you mention. And any other information. This goes without saying.

(Your general concept that you'd be "hurting" those parties, is both (A) misguided and anyway (B) irrelevant. There won't be any "Bad rep down the road!!" It is one legal action in a billion, nobody will remember your name by this afternoon. The normal world is nothing like a TV Series such as *Goliath*. It's a total non-issue.)

So,

1. You need an employment solicitor at this time - this morning.
2. Your solicitor will use the information you mention. And any other information. No issue.

Comment: "_There won't be any "Bad rep down the road!!" It is one legal action in a billion_". I remember coworkers from 10+ years ago and there are some I'd definitely not recommend based on my past experiences with them. I've also, similarly, inquired about people on the grapevine coming from jobs I used to work at. Maybe the CEO of a company with 100,000 employees isn't going to remember you from a lawsuit but a random peon might.

Comment: It's a small world, and what goes around comes around. When I started my first job as a trainee, a fellow-trainee was almost fired over personal behavior issues. 30 years later, I was being interviewed for another job in a different company by that same trainee. He didn't remember me, but I remembered him (and I didn't even consider accepting the job!)

Answer (score 4):

TLDR

1. Meet with a lawyer, and get his professional opinion
2. Follow his advice to the letter.
3. Update your resume
4. Move on.

More detailed advice.  If your company is playing hardball, you need the advice of a lawyer to negotiate an exit.  Do not face this on your own, or you may end up cheating yourself out of owed monies, or getting blackballed in your industry.

A lawyer can help you negotiate your exit, and have them include clauses regarding pay, a positive reference, and anything that will protect you or be to your benefit.

Do not try to fight this on your own.  Make sure your resume is updated, and be prepared to walk away.

Comment: @MarkBooth mine is.  Why, are you assuming his gender?

Comment: You didn't say to meet with *your* lawyer, you said to meet with *a* lawyer. The phrases "get *their* professional opinion" and "Follow *their* advice" would be less insulting to 36% of the U.S. legal profession (49% in the U.K.)!

Comment: @MarkBooth I hardly see how the gender of my lawyer is relevant to the question in any way unless you're just trolling

Comment: @MarkBooth and I didn't say to meet with the entire firm, one lawyer should be sufficient

Comment: I was not talking about the gender of your lawyer (you brought that up), I was talking, about your presumption that all layers are male. This is not inclusive, and it is not respectful to the legal profession. I would suggest that you review the Workplace [code of conduct](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/conduct): "Be inclusive and respectful ... Prefer gender-neutral language ... If a situation makes it hard to be friendly, stop participating and move on. "

Comment: @MarkBooth I agree, you should stop participating

Comment: @MarkBooth I'm autistic and cannot deviate from the speech as I learned it, I'm sorry if you are too ablist to accept that, and to assume bad intent on my part.  I see no need for you to harass someone based on his disability, and I am feeling very threatened right now.

Comment: Thank you for making me aware. I accept your explanation, and can see now how I might have misinterpreted your 'assumption of gender'. I hope you can understand that since I was not previously aware that you were autistic, I was unable to take it into account when assessing your intent.